# Send Email When Match in Firebase Database

Tags: angularjs, email, firebase, server, angularfire

I'm trying to build a web app using AngularJS and Firebase that sends an email to two users that match on certain parameters.  The users submit their information first and if there is a match with another person in the database, I want to send an email to both those people.  For example, if two people, A and B both have the age of 25, I would like to send A and B an email with certain information.  Is this possible using Firebase?

Answer (score 12):

### If you are NOT running a server

**Yes**

You could achieve it by using a service like [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/firebase/mandrill/).

You could create a zap linking FireBase and an e-mail service like Mandrill.

```
A Zap combines triggers and actions — whenever the trigger event occurs, Zapier automatically completes the action for you!
```

When there is a match, update a special key in your FireBase database.

As Zapier is listening to updates of that particular key, it will react by sending your e-mails via Mandrill.

**March 2017 UPDATE**

New tools have now been added to Firebase to trigger database event handlers:

- database events triggers: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events
- cloud functions for FireBase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase
- using cloud functions to send e-mails through sendGrid:
  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/sendgrid

---

### If you are running a server

Your server can easily check the values in FireBase and send e-mails accordingly. That would then be a

**Yes, of course** :)

Comment: Thanks for you response Manube.  I am new to programming, so forgive me for the stupid questions, but when you say if you are running a server, do you mean like a nodejs server?  Could you explain that further please?  Also, if I was not running a server and I used Zapier, would I be able to send emails to A and B with custom information on A (on the database, like his/her age) in the email to B and vice versa to A?  How would I do this?

Comment: yes, a nodejs server is very much appropriate and works well with angularjs. However, there is a steep learning curve. With Firebase, you can send anything you want to it via ajax/$http calls. When Zapier detects a change at the proper FireBase key, it will tell your email service to send an email. It can relay to it the info detected in your Firebase.

Comment: Awesome!  One last question:  Should I be worried that I am doing this on the client side?  Can anyone view my source code and play around with the code that checks my database and triggers the email, so that they can send emails to anyone?  I am worried about this, but like you said, it would be great if I can avoid nodejs for the time being

Comment: not if you make your calls to firebase with https; other than that, firebase is one of the safest solution without a server

Comment: @user3161565 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Zapier is no longer an option for loading data from Firebase

Comment: @Manube Do you happen to know of any alternative now that Firebase triggers are deprecated from Zapier and are not guaranteed to work? I have Zapier and Sendgrid set up without a server. Thank you so much

Comment: @Script Kitty well serverless functions are getting all over the place these days: you could do it with an AWS Lambda function, that would check your Firebase and send emails

Comment: I stumbled across this post whilst searching for a similar answer. It seems that Zapier no longer supports observing Firebase nodes... any other alternatives?

Comment: @manube you might like to update your answer now that Firebase have announced email capable Cloud Functions. :)

Comment: @ajostergaard you are right, two years have passed since this answer was posted, and more options are now available. Thanks for mentioning this, will update...