# Email notifications in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, email

I would like to know if anyone knows a way where you can send an email when a specific node in firebase is created, updated or deleted?

More specifically, I have a web service where users can book each other for a period of time. I use Firebase as the backend to store user information and so on but I want to send a confirmation to the users' email address whenever a booking has occurred. I understand that this has previously been possible using Zapier, however they no longer support Firebase.

Anyone who has a workaround or an idea on how to send email notifications in Firebase?

Comment: Do you work with a private backend-server or only firebase?

Comment: Since Zapier no longer works, only [option 2 from this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656191/send-email-when-match-in-firebase-database) remains: run your own app server.

Comment: @tobifasc I work with a firebase server and also have an account on godaddy where I host the actual web page.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't help you with godaddy. I don't have experience with it. But basically firebase has the ability to listen to data-updates.

Comment: @tobiasfc So, what you are suggesting is that I create some sort of server side script that will listen for these events and then send an email. I have only experience with web development, mostly javascript and a little bit of PHP, do you have any recommendations or resources on how to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After searching some more I found that there is no direct plugin. I contacted the firebase support team and they are considering to create this functionality themselves; however, when and how is not yet decided. 
There are different possibilities but they all require some kind of back end coding, meaning a server that can watch for these changes. 
I landed on [node.js](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/node-js-tutorial) as this is most similar to what I usually work on, i.e. javascript. 
By including [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer) and [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) through npm, **sending emails based on firebase event was achieved like this**:

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

var mainApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    //firebase authentication
});

var directTransport = require('nodemailer-direct-transport');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var options = {};
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(directTransport(options))

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'example.gmail.com'
        pass: 'password'
    }
});

var nodeToWatch = mainApp.database().ref('node_to_watch'); //firebase node to watch

nodeToWatch.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) { //fires once for every node in this location
    if(!childSnapshot.val().email_sent){ //check if email has already been sent

            nodeToWatch.child(childSnapshot.key).child('email_sent').set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).then(function(response){ //set email value to sent

                var data = JSON.stringify(childSnapshot.val(), null, 9); //stringify the response so we can attach it in the email

                // create template based sender function
                var sendInfo = transporter.templateSender({
                    subject: 'Node in firebase updated',
                    html: 'Hello, data for new node is: {{data}}
                }, {
                from: 'example.gmail.com'
                });

                // use template based sender to send a message
                sendInfo({
                    to: 'exampleRecipient.email.com'
                }, {
                    data: data //data variable to insert into email
                }, function(err, info){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log('Email sent');
                    }
                });
            });

    }

});
```

This example listens for the firebase `on_child_added` event but any [firebase event](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html) will work. Hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: Is there another way instead of adding the password? I don't have experience in node, but the password could be read by inspecting the web? I know that it's not the best solution, but I added a webview which load a php mail script when the data is added

Comment: I forgot to say I put the webview hidden

Comment: @Jaco Don't do that. If you're going to use `nodemailer` do it in Firebase Functions (or something else on the server side)

Comment: Do not do this in the browser unless you want your email account to get compromised.